# Applying different time series models (ARIMA, HOLT-WINTER) on the basis of MAPE

Tags: r, time-series, arima, mape

I have a time series object `calc_visit_ts`. **I want to apply the best fit time series model based on the MAPE value for each model.** The issue I face is that the MAPE value HOLT-WINTER multiplicative model cannot be calculated in the same way as the other models(as it gives me a different MAPE value when compared to `summary(visit_model_Hw_M)`).

```
#### AUTO-ARIMA
visit_model_Arima <- auto.arima(calc_visit_ts)
# summary(visit_model_Arima)

#### HOLT-WINTER ADDITIVE
visit_model_Hw_A <- hw(calc_visit_ts,h=monthly_prediction,seasonal = "additive")
# summary(visit_model_Hw_A)

#### HOLT-WINTER MULTIPLICATIVE
visit_model_Hw_M <- hw(calc_visit_ts,h=monthly_prediction,seasonal = "multiplicative")
# summary(visit_model_Hw_M)


#### Calculating MAPE on models for best suit
model_Mape<- c( MAPE_model(visit_model_Arima)
                ,MAPE_model(visit_model_Hw_A))
                #,MAPE_model(visit_model_Hw_M))  this is not accurate

model_Mape=na.omit(model_Mape)
token<-which(min(model_Mape)==model_Mape)

if(length(token)>0)
{
  if(token==1)
    {visit_model<-visit_model_Arima
  }else if(token==2)
    {visit_model<-visit_model_Hw_A
  }else if(token==3)
    {visit_model<-visit_model_Hw_M
  }else 
  {
    ##EXCEPTION HANDLING  
  }
}

summary(visit_model)
```

And here is the **function I use to perform MAPE calculation** on the models -

```
MAPE_model <- function(visit_model) {
 #CHECK FOR ZERO CONDIITION  if(visit_model$x!=0)
 mape = mean(abs(visit_model$residuals)/visit_model$x)
 return(mape)
}
```

**Data** for time series -

```
calc_visit_ts
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012          35  53  65  60  64  49  63  55  59  66
2013  62  54  77  67  84  62  82  65  59  67  60  67
2014  73  75  55  76  93  96  89  76  88  65  83  82
2015  76  72  75  94  91  83  72  73  80  83  81  81
2016  97  91  90  80 101  98  

dput(calc_visit_ts)
structure(c(35, 53, 65, 60, 64, 49, 63, 55, 59, 66, 62, 54, 77, 
67, 84, 62, 82, 65, 59, 67, 60, 67, 73, 75, 55, 76, 93, 96, 89, 
76, 88, 65, 83, 82, 76, 72, 75, 94, 91, 83, 72, 73, 80, 83, 81, 
81, 97, 91, 90, 80, 101, 98), .Tsp = c(2012.16666666667, 2016.41666666667, 
12), class = "ts")
```

To show exactly what I mean -

**Holt-Winter Additive Plot**

[image: Holt-Winter Additive Plot]

**Holt-Winter Multiplicative Plot**
[image: Holt-Winter Multiplicative Plot]

The **issue** is `summary(visit_model_Hw_M)` gives `MAPE = 9.075097`
whereas, `MAPE_model(visit_model_Hw_M)` gives `0.001273087` because the multiplicative model fits the curve(data points) therefore using `visit_model_Hw_M$residuals` isn't an appropriate way to calculate the MAPE(as the function tries to fit the curve).

Is there a way I can fetch the MAPE value for HOLT-WINTER multiplicative from the summary itself? OR a way to correctly estimate the MAPE value for the HOLT-WINTER multiplicative model?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You say *...cannot be calculated in the same way as the other models (as it gives me a different MAPE value when compared to summary(visit_model_Hw_M)).* Why is that?

Comment: Basically, I cannot use HW(multiplicative) because it tries to fit the curve. Calculating the resulting MAPE from `visit_model_Hw_M$residuals` leads me to a unexpected value.

Comment: Don't all models fit curves? What you need is extract residuals and get their MAPE, ain't that the case?

Comment: I've edited the question. Sure models fit curves, but not HW(multiplicative) more so than others. I shall add a plot of a difference between the HW(A) and HW(M) models to give a better idea.

Comment: Well, it seems that the multiplicative model fits the curve perfectly... But perhaps you could compare MAPEs of out-of-sample predictions? That could be more fair than comparing in-sample fits; the latter will be prone to overfitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation over the data and trial and error I found that the MAPEs for `ARIMA` and `Holt-Winter` models are calculated differently -

```
MAPE_model <- function(visit_model,model_type) {
 if(model_type == "ARIMA")
  mape = mean(abs(visit_model$residuals)/visit_model$x)
 if(model_type == "HW")
  mape = mean(abs(visit_model$x - visit_model$fitted)/visit_model$x)
 else
  mape = -1  #Something
 return(mape)
}
```

While the notation `visit_model$x - visit_model$fitted` is canonically equivalent to `visit_model$residuals` in the `ARIMA` and `Holt-Winter(additive)` it is not the case in `Holt-Winter(multiplicative)` model. Hence, the distinction by `model_type`